# FBSDKAppInviteDialog always launches browser

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I need to send app invites in my app and want to use the native iOS Facebook app (if installed) for it.

I'm running it on my iPhone with iOS 9.0.1 with the native Facebook app installed, however the dialog always launches the browser. It just does not launch the Facebook app.

This is my code:

```
let appLinkUrl:NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://fb.me/xxx")!

var inviteContent:FBSDKAppInviteContent = FBSDKAppInviteContent()
inviteContent.appLinkURL = appLinkUrl

FBSDKAppInviteDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: inviteContent, delegate: self)
```

My info.plist looks like this

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>

<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>xxx</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>xxx</string>

<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

And additionally all `NSAppTransportSecurity` related entries like in the quickstart guide.

Comment: Correct. It is because of changes Apple made to iOS9

Comment: @WizKid so there is no way of launching the Facebook app for this?

Comment: @WizKid this is not true! As their documentation clearly says `Facebook Login is not required for app invites because the experience takes place in the Facebook native mobile app.`

Comment: Can you link to that so I can tell then to change it

Comment: @WizKid it's stated here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/overview

Comment: Thanks. I will tell them to update it

Comment: I have the same issue, any update about this?

Comment: https://itunes.apple.com/hk/app/kiwi-q-a/id965609252?mt=8 This application is sending app invite inside its application by selecting friends from tableview listing any idea how this can be done?
Are they not following facebook guidelines?

Comment: @user1039695 Pretty sure they're treating Kiwi as a "game" which allows them to get the friend data needed to display names/images... and then (I think) lets them send notifications to friends.

Answer (score 0):

As per the iOS 9, the link should be open in Safari browser. Here the below link,

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/786729821439894/?search_id